# send process output to a file

Tags: windows, cmd

How can I send process output to a file, without closing the process in Windows.

In cmd I use: "my_program.exe > file.txt". It send output of my_program to file.txt but it happends only when my_program finished, I need to send output to file.txt while my_program is running.

Comment: The output goes to the file as soon as your program produces it. What makes you think it only writes when it's finished?

Comment: Probably some sort of buffered i/o or flush issue. Make sure your program is writing out end-of-line (`\n`) characters with each output or invoking the appropriate "flush" function.

Comment: @selbie, Windows never uses line buffering, so `\n` won't help.